# SQL find which OR was matched

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In a statement like: `SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE row1=val1 OR row2=val2`, is it possible to know which row was matched? If so how could it be done? And how would you capture this in PHP?

Comment: Yes, inside `SELECT` part you must add code to show which of 2 conditions is met as an extra column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Case/IF` statement

```
SELECT *,
       case when row1='val1' then 'row1' else 'row2' end as matched col
FROM tbl1
WHERE row1='val1' OR row2='val2'
```

`Case` statement can be replaced with `IF` statement like this

```
IF(row1='val1','row1','row2')
```

Comment: Sidenote: Curious if `IF(row1=` shouldn't be `IF(row1==` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, single `=` is what required

Comment: Ok thanks. I was Googling it in the meantime. *Cheers*

Comment: Where does `THEN` print to? Can I capture the result in PHP?

Comment: @Krii It will be part of select query result